# python class instances referring to same location

Tags: python

I have a class called `Door` and a class called `Window`. It's a child class to a class named `Furniture`. My program reads excel files, loops over it 2 times, first time reading / writing everything about doors , the second time about windows. Simplified, I have the following code:

```
for gathering_inf in ('door', 'window'):
    for row in file:
        if gathering_inf == 'door' and currently reading door line:
            furniture = Door(width, height, description)
        if gatherig_inf == 'window' and currently reading window line:
            furniture = Window(width, height, description)

        # Now do something with the furniture object ..
```

The weird think that happens is, if I for example (as shown above) print the object `furniture`, I get their location and, some of the objects' location in memory is the same, even though they are two different instances width different attributes. For example:

```
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE810>
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE890>
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE810>
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE890>
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE8B0>
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE8D0>
<__main__.Door object at 0x03BFE8B0>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE8D0>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE8B0>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE890>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE8B0>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE890>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE8B0>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE890>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE8B0>
<__main__.Window object at 0x03BFE890>
```

Could someone explain to me why python behaves this way?

Comment: is it a typo in your second if clause, you are checking against a variable gathering_ing?

Comment: yes, it was a typo. i'm editing my post accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the reference-counting garbage collector. As soon as a new object is assigned to `furniture` the GC will delete the object and thus its memory location can be re-used by a new object.

---

Here's a small demo showing this behaviour. Note that because of the way the Python REPL works (it keeps a reference to the last result in `_`) the addresses will alternate.

```
>>> foo = object(); foo
<object object at 0x7fd74cd390a0>
>>> foo = object(); foo
<object object at 0x7fd74cd390b0>
>>> foo = object(); foo
<object object at 0x7fd74cd390a0>
>>> foo = object(); foo
<object object at 0x7fd74cd390b0>
>>> foo = object(); foo
<object object at 0x7fd74cd390a0>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I was afraid i had a bug in my code or something :d. It's something i shouldn't be worried about, right?

Answer (score 1):

[ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) pretty much nailed it: *It's the way that the Python Virtual Machine works.*

What you are observing is the specifics of the **CPython** implemetaion of the *Reference counting Garbage collector*. **CPython** in your case is garbage collecting the `Door` object, and then creating a new `Window` object, and then reuses the (now garbage collected) `Door` object's location, storing the `Window` object there.

It is in fact common to see **CPython** reuse addresses of objects that were previously garbage collected. *For instance, running ThiefMaster's code on my computer I got slightly different (rotational) results:*

[image: CPython memory usage]

At this point it is important to note that this behaviour is `CPython` specific. For instance, [Enthought's Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) doesn't seem to produce similar results, however I do not know if this inconsistency is a matter of implementation difference:

[image]